# View pager images(fragments) slider from the start

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have implemented slider in `ViewPager` its working fine when click on play button, but now I am trying to implement slider from last item button "play form start again", but I am stuck how can I implement this I have implemented slider to play form current item, but I can't not do it from last item to play again I am using `Executors` this is my code for sliding

```
  /**
 * starts the slide show with 2 seconds frequency
 */
public void startTimer(final boolean isStartFromCurrentItem) {
    isTimerPlaying = true;
    btn_pause_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
    scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate
            (new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // call service


                    Message msg = new Message();

                    Log.i("change", "change");

                    hanleMessage(msg, isStartFromCurrentItem);


                }
            }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}
/**
 * UI Handler of background thread, this handler called after every two seconds to show next item as slide view
 *
 * @param message
 * @param isStartFromCurrentItem
 */
private void hanleMessage(Message message, final boolean isStartFromCurrentItem) {
    Handler msg_handler = new Handler(getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            if (viewpager != null) {
                if (viewpager.getCurrentItem() == cursor.getCount() - 1) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.slide_show_comp), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    stopSchedueler();
                    btn_pause_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);

                } else {

                    if (isStartFromCurrentItem) {
                        int old_pos = viewpager.getCurrentItem();
                        viewpager.setCurrentItem(old_pos + 1, true);
                    } else {

                        Log.e("getCurrentItem", viewpager.getCurrentItem() + "");
                        viewpager.setCurrentItem(0, true);


                        //for starting slide show from beginning


                    }
                }
            }


        }
    };

    msg_handler.sendMessage(message);


}
```

If I want to play slides form current item simply call `startTimer(true)` and handling in second method is working fine and when I call this method from last item where is button "play again" I call `tartTimer(false)` how can I start slider from beginning by changing in this method after passing `false` can someone please give me optimised solution thanks.

Comment: I think you can use the boolean variable that you have in the handle message method. Like if isStartFromCurrent is false then it means you want  to start from the beginning and then you can set the current item of view pager to the first item

Comment: by setting position to 0 i am able to start  from `viewpager.setCurrentItem(0, true);` from start but how can i increment in 1 so next image can become visible as i did in    `int old_pos = viewpager.getCurrentItem();  viewpager.setCurrentItem(old_pos + 1, true);`
should i define local int and increment it by 1 every time or is there any better approach?

Comment: you can set old pos to 0 too

Comment: plz check my edited comment

Comment: after setting to zero your increment should work fine the way you are doing right now

Answer (score 0):

you can set viewPager.setcurrentitem(0) to start your viewpager from start when you press play form start again button

Comment: by setting position to 0 i am able to start from viewpager.setCurrentItem(0, true); from start but how can i increment in 1 so next image can become visible as i did in int old_pos = viewpager.getCurrentItem(); viewpager.setCurrentItem(old_pos + 1, true); should i define local int and increment it by 1 every time or is there any better approach?

Comment: ViewPager automatically increase the view position when you swipe right